# Nav bar will not stay on one side of the webpage

Tags: html, css

I require help. My problem is that, I try to move all my text and images to one side of the webpage and leave the navbar. However my navbar is moving along with the text. I will put my code below.

The Problem-
i.stack.imgur.(com)/rLIjl.(png)
Html-
[my html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDrTj.png)

CSS- 
[my css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdbIb.png)

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* Note that by "in the question itself" we mean that it has to be text, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Try the css rule:

```
ul.navbar { position: static }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to achive but I think you are trying to put the navbar and the text side by side. In order to do that you can use:

```
<div style="float:[right/left];">
<!-- your content -->
</div>
```

to make your content float to the right or to the left. 
In this case, this could be a possible solution for your problem:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prova-css.css">
</head>
<body>

<div style="float:left;">
  <img src="img.jpg" style="width:191px;height:158px;">

  <ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Third</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div style="float:right; width:70%;">
  <h1>Title</h1>

  <p>Welcome to Shoe Nation!
  <p>(This site is currently under construnction)

  <adress>Something</adress>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  padding-left: 11em;
  background-color:#FAEAD3;
  color:#FF3B3F;
}

ul.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I've already saw your html, but again it's not clear what's the final result you want to get

Comment: Ok, in my code, everything but the Links/navbar was supposed to move, however the navbar also moved along with everything else. Is there a way to fix this.